# Rotary encoder noise with MCP23017 chips

Tags: gpio, pi-zero

I want to use multiple rotary encoders with my Raspberry Pi Zero so I have connected two MCP23017 port exander chips liked to addresses `0x20` and `0x21`, and I am using the [MCP23017-python library](https://github.com/sensorberg/MCP23017-python/blob/master/src/mcp23017.py). These are my connections for both MCP23017 chips:

**Chip 1:**

- VDD and RESET - linked to 5 volts
- VSS - linked to ground
- A0, A1, A2 - linked to ground

**Chip 2:**

- VDD and RESET - linked to 5 volts
- VSS - linked to ground
- A0 - linked to 5 volts
- A1, A2 - linked to ground

With the code below I can get multiple encoders working ok when connected to one chip (one address in `mcp_addresses` and one array in `knob_maps`), but when I want to add another chip I get a lot of nonsense results and usually get the wrong rotation appearing. Also sometimes when I connect another chip and I click down on a registered encoder button I get a turn being read. Why would this be the case?

I have tried debouncing solutions by putting delays in between value readings but I've not been able to remove the noise, and things work fine when I only have one chip configured in the code. Is there a better way of coding things? I have tried reading interrupts but this produces even more nonsensical results. What can I do to get reliable readings?

Any help would be much appreciated!

**Code:**

```
from mcp23017 import *
from i2c import I2C
import time
import threading
import smbus

GPPUA = 0x0c
GPPUB = 0x0d
IODIRA = 0x00

mcp_addresses = [0x20, 0x21]
mcps = []

for x, address in enumerate(mcp_addresses):
    bus0 = smbus.SMBus(1)

    # set all pull up resistors
    bus0.write_byte_data(address, GPPUA, 0xFF)
    bus0.write_byte_data(address, GPPUB, 0xFF)

    # set all GPA pins as input
    bus0.write_byte_data(address, IODIRA, 0xFF)

    # creates a I2C Object as a wrapper for the SMBus
    i2c = I2C(bus0)

    # creates an MCP object with the given address
    mcp = MCP23017(address, i2c)

    mcps.append(mcp)
    time.sleep(0.5)

knob_maps = [
    [
        {
            "rotary": [0, 1], # encoder connected to gpio pins GPA0 and GPA1
            "rotary_param": "gate_0_0",
            "push": None,
            "push_param": None,
        },
        {
            "rotary": [2, 3],
            "rotary_param": "gate_0_0",
            "push": None,
            "push_param": None,
        },
        {
            "rotary": [4, 5],
            "rotary_param": "gate_0_1",
            "push": 6, # encoder button connected to GPA4
            "push_param": "push_param_0_1",
        },
    ],
    [
        {
            "rotary": [0, 1],
            "rotary_param": "gate_1_0",
            "push": None,
            "push_param": None,
        },
        {
            "rotary": [2, 3],
            "rotary_param": "gate_1_1",
            "push": None,
            "push_param": None,
        },
        {
            "rotary": [4, 5],
            "rotary_param": "gate_1_1",
            "push": None,
            "push_param": None,
        },
    ],
]

class Rotary:
    def setup(self):
        print('Creating rotary...')

    def __init__(self, the_mcp=None, clk=None, dt=None, sw=None, bounce=500, rotary_param="blank param"):
        self.pins = { "clk": clk, "dt": dt, "sw": sw }
        self.bounce = bounce
        self.the_mcp = the_mcp
        self.rotary_param = rotary_param
        self.setup()

    def watch(self, stop_event):
        tick = 0
        pressed = 0
        last_val_4 = self.the_mcp.digital_read(self.pins['clk'])
        last_val_5 = self.the_mcp.digital_read(self.pins['dt'])

        if self.the_mcp != None:
            time.sleep(1)
            while not stop_event.is_set():
                # button pressing
                if self.pins['sw'] is not None:
                    swState = self.the_mcp.digital_read(self.pins['sw'])
                    if swState == 0:
                        if pressed < int((time.time() * 1000) - self.bounce):
                            pressed = int(time.time() * 1000)
                            print("pressed", self.rotary_param)
                            time.sleep(0.1)

                # rotation
                val_4 = self.the_mcp.digital_read(self.pins['clk'])
                if val_4 != last_val_4:
                    val_5 = self.the_mcp.digital_read(self.pins['dt'])
                    if val_5 != val_4:
                        if tick == 0:
                            print("up", val_4, val_5, self.rotary_param)
                            tick += 1
                        else:
                            tick = 0
                    else:
                        if tick == 0:
                            print("down", val_4, val_5, self.rotary_param)
                            tick += 1
                        else:
                            tick = 0
                last_val_4 = val_4
                time.sleep(0.0001)

    def start(self):
        self.stop_event = threading.Event()
        self.th = threading.Thread(target=self.watch, args=[self.stop_event])
        self.th.setDaemon(True)
        self.th.start()
    
    def stop(self):
        self.stop_event.set()

rotaries = []

for index, i in enumerate(knob_maps):
    for obj in knob_maps[index]:
        # creating the rotary object, mapping it to different MCP chips
        rot = Rotary(
            the_mcp=mcps[index], clk=obj["rotary"][0], dt=obj["rotary"][1],
            sw=obj["push"], bounce=500, rotary_param=obj["rotary_param"]
        )
        time.sleep(0.1)
        rot.start()
        rotaries.append(rot)

time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Program is starting ... ')
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(10)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Stopping...")
```